# C# WPF Chart Binding Failed when use UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I tried to use UserControl to show my data chart view. When I use the codes below without using UserControl view, it works. I could see the trend line.

```
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
 <TabItem Header="ChartView">
                <Grid Background="LightGray">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="8*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="8*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="1">
                        <WrapPanel>
                            <DataGrid Width="500" Height="50"/>
                            <Button Margin="10" Content="Refresh" />
                            <Button Margin="10" Content="Export" />
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="1" Background="AliceBlue">
                        <Label Content="Point" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="0.5"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <c:Chart
                        BorderBrush="Black"
                        BorderThickness="0.5"
                        Background="White"
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        Margin="1"
                        DataContext="{Binding ViewModels[0]}" 
                        <!--I made a collection of VM in MainViewModel for data binding-->
                        Items="{Binding Items1}"
                        UseZoom="True"
                        View="{Binding View1}" />
                    </Grid>
```

[chart view without using UserControl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m13Qp.png)

But when I moved the same code to UserControl view, it cannot show graph.....Belows are the code in the UserControl ,so how can I fix it ?

```
 <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:MainViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid Background="LightGray">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="8*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="8*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="1">
            <WrapPanel>
                <DataGrid Width="500" Height="50" />
                <Button Margin="10" Content="Refresh" />
                <Button Margin="10" Content="Export" />
            </WrapPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel
            Grid.Row="1"
            Margin="1"
            Background="AliceBlue">
            <Label
                Padding="0.5"
                Content="Point"
                FontWeight="Bold" />
        </StackPanel>
        <c:Chart
            Grid.Row="2"
            Margin="1"
            Background="White"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="0.5"
            DataContext="{Binding ViewModels[0]}"
            Items="{Binding Items1}"
            UseZoom="True"
            View="{Binding View1}" />
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Margin="1">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <WrapPanel Grid.Column="0" Background="LightGoldenrodYellow">
                    <Label
                        Padding="0.5"
                        Content="Glass Average"
                        FontWeight="Bold" />
                </WrapPanel>
                <WrapPanel Grid.Column="1" Background="Wheat">
                    <Label
                        Padding="0.5"
                        Content="Panel Average"
                        FontWeight="Bold" />
                </WrapPanel>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid Grid.Row="4" Margin="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <c:Chart
                Grid.Column="0"
                Margin="1"
                Background="White"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="0.5"
                DataContext="{Binding ViewModels[0]}"
                Items="{Binding Items2}"
                UseZoom="True"
                View="{Binding View2}" />
            <c:Chart
                Grid.Column="1"
                Margin="1"
                Background="White"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="0.5"
                DataContext="{Binding ViewModels[0]}"
                Items="{Binding Items3}"
                UseZoom="True"
                View="{Binding View3}" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

[chart view with using UserControl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUtdR.png)

Comment: Be aware that the MainViewModel in the UserControl's DataContext is a different instance than the one in the Window's DataContext. If you are using the UserControl inside the Window, remove the DataContext assignment from the UserControl's XAML. The DataContext would then automatically be inherited by the UserControl.

Comment: @Clemens OK I'll try it again. Thx~